# Invertibility of a nonlinear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have an operator of the form
$$ T(u)(x)= u(x)+F(u(x))-\int_{\Omega}F(u(x))\mathrm{d}x, $$
where $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $|\Omega|=1$, and $F\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, nonlinear, strictly increasing and $F(-x)=-F(x)$. I am particularly interested in the case when $F$ grows faster than linearly, so for example we can choose $F(y)=y^3$.

The domain of $T$ is $V=\{f\in L^\infty: \int_\Omega f(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0\}$.

Under these assumptions, can I determine that $T$ is invertible?

Below are my ideas so far. I would really any hints what else I could use or what I missed.

a) I tried to solve the equation $T(u)=f$ by using Banach or Schauder fixed point theorems. It seems that without any bounds on $F'$ it is impossible to obtain a contraction, and for Schauder I cannot get the compactness of $T$.

b) It is clear that $T$ is one-to-one: if we multiply $T(u_1)-T(u_2)$ by $u_1-u_2$ and integrate, we have
$$ \int (T(u_1)-T(u_2))(u_1-u_2)\mathrm{d}x = \|u_1-u_2\|_2^2 + \int (F(u_1)-F(u_2))(u_1-u_2) \mathrm{d}x. $$
Due to the monotonicity of $F$, the last integral is always non-negative, so if $T(u_1)=T(u_2)$ then $\|u_2-u_2\|_2=0$ as well. It also means that the operator $T$ is monotone.

c) By b), it suffices to show that $T$ is surjective. I found the theorem about the monotone operators which says that if $A$ is a continuous monotone operator with $D(A)=H$ (where $H$ is a Hilbert space), then $R(I+A)=H$. However, in my case I cannot extend the domain to whole $L^2$ because then $F(u)$ might not be integrable (unless we can bound $F$ by some linear function, which is not the case I'm particularly interested in).

d) As the real-valued function $G(y)=y+F(y)$ is invertible, it is clear that the operator
$T_1(u)(x)=G(u(x))$, $T_1\colon L^\infty\to L^\infty$ is invertible as well. Then we can write $T$ as $PT_1$, where $P$ is a projection onto $V$, namely $Pf=f-\int f\mathrm{d}x$. I was wondering if writing $T$ in terms of the projection $P$ would be helpful, but I didn't get to any conclusion.